# How to handle double click (dblclick) event on row with data in kendo-grid in Angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-grid, double-click, ondblclick

I'm using **Angular2** & **TS** with`kendo-grid` and it allows to get the data of the clicked row, but only for

**singleClick** => `(cellClick)="onCellClick($event.dataItem)"`

, not **doubleClick** => `(dblclick)="onDblClick(<<CANNOT_GET_ROW_DATA_HERE>>)`

How to an event on dblclick, not cellClick, but with exact row we want?

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple.

You've just got to add both event listeners to your `<kendo-grid>` options.

```
    <kendo-grid
                (cellClick)="onCellClick($event.dataItem)"
                (dblclick)="onDblClick()">
```

and then in your `controller`:

1. Add a new global field:

`class MyClass { clickedRowItem: myObject; ..... }`

2. Assign the value from `cellClick` to this field:

`onCellClick(dataItem: myObject) { this.clickedRowItem = trackerId; }`

3. Run the dblFunction with the field as the argument:

`onDblClick() { this.myFunctionToFire(this.clickedRowItem); }`